# Small time table using Genetic Algorithm

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to solve this problem using genetic algorithm. But can't find any way to calculate fitness value. I am not writing a program instead I am just solving this on a paper.
Problem is I can't find the fitness value which caters the clashes. e.g. class1 and class2 can't be on same day.

Each professor can only teach one class at a time.

**Days**
Monday
Wednesday
Friday

**The classes are:**
Class 1 - Intro to Programming: meets from 8:00-9:00am.
Class 2 - Intro to Artificial Intelligence: meets from 8:30-9:30am
Class 3 - Natural Language Processing: meets from 9:00-10:00am
Class 4 - Computer Vision: meets from 9:00-10:00am
Class 5 - Machine Learning: meets from 9:30-10:30am

**The professors are:**
Professor A, who is available to teach Classes 3 and 4.
Professor B, who is available to teach Classes 2, 3, 4, and 5.
Professor C, who is available to teach Classes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Help us out: what does your fitness func look like now?

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, a fitness function needs to indicate how many clashes are created by a solution, so you would have something like negative values. E.g. -100 when classes clash, and -50 when profs clash. A fitness value of 0 would be then a solution that fulfills all required constraints.

Then you could also add some logic to honor solutions with good balancing of professor workload. A simple idea would be to take the difference between least and highest prof workload into account. The smaller the difference, the higher the fitness value should be. Either you subtract the difference again, like for the constraints, or you invert it, e.g. 100/diff.